# Google Sheets: transpose table with operation on columns

Tags: google-sheets

On google Sheets I have a table with these fields

- Category: House
- - Price (int)
- - Surface (int)
- - Rooms (int)
- - Bathrooms (int)
- - Garden (int)
- Category: Services (distance in km)
- - Supermarket (int)
- - Pharmacy (int)
- - School (int)
- - Bar (int)
- Category: Activities (true if in a 10km radius)
- - Theatre (bool)
- - Gym (bool)
- - High School (bool)
- - Park (bool)
- - Swimming pool (bool)

Now, on sheet1 this is a table where each field is a column.

On Sheet2 I want to transpose this in Rows. If I use the formula TRANSPOSE it will work.
My issue is I want:

- Category House: to be simply copied
- Category Services: One single row with the Average values of all fields in Services
- Category Activies: one single row which is True if there are more trues then falses and viceversa

Do you know if I can operate a change using TRANSPOSE formula (or any other formulas)?

EDIT:
[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zDKfIZM1Z4Bj6COeQnbRvW5-gIlejfoseLSmDfGf6Zg/edit?usp=sharing) there is a link to a Google Sheets Sample you can test. I would like to know if I can do what I did with one single formula at cell A1

Comment: Pls share a spreadsheet. People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

In A7, try

```
=transpose({"Serices";"Average distance";arrayformula(mmult(value(Table!G3:J5);transpose(column(Table!G3:J5)^0)/COLUMNS(Table!G3:J5)))})
```

In A8, try

```
=transpose({"Activities";"AreActivities";arrayformula(1=round(mmult(1*(Table!K3:O5);transpose(column(Table!K3:O5)^0))/COLUMNS(Table!K3:O5)))})
```

or in A1 by one single formula

```
={TRANSPOSE(Table!A1:F5);
transpose({"Serices";"Average distance";arrayformula(mmult(value(Table!G3:J5);transpose(column(Table!G3:J5)^0)/COLUMNS(Table!G3:J5)))});
transpose({"Activities";"AreActivities";arrayformula(1=round(mmult(1*(Table!K3:O5);transpose(column(Table!K3:O5)^0))/COLUMNS(Table!K3:O5)))})}
```

Reference
[MMULT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094292)